# how to rectify this "SQL syntax" in php&mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, tagging

i'm trying to create a tagging sys demo here. And i'm stumped why i get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '#ok )' at line 1

here is my code:

```
$insert=mysqli_query($conn, 'insert into `hashtag` (posts) values ('.$data1.')') or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your variable $data1 contains something that isn't valid SQL syntax. Consider using prepared queries, so that your input data doesn't need to get near the SQL parser. (This will help you avoid SQL injection attacks.)

Answer (score -1):

In  mysqli query you don't have to put $conn .
Just remove it and in query put like this '".$data1."' And check.

Comment: That'll fail if $data1 ever contains `"` though. Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).